# jQuery sliding table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

My ASP.Net application generates an `<asp:Table>` from the codebehind.  What I need is for the header row of that table to slide down the page as the user scrolls past it.

I've tried the following approach using JavaScript:

```
window.onscroll = function () {

    //grab the current scroll position
    var scrollY = document.body.scrollTop;
    if (scrollY == 0) {
        if (window.pageYOffset)
            scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
        else
            scrollY = (document.body.parentElement) ? document.body.parentElement.scrollTop : 0;
    }

    //grab the position of the header row I want to slide
    var head = $("tr[name='headerrow']").offset();
    var headtop = head.top;
    var headleft = head.left;

    //if the user has scrolled past the top of the header row
    if (scrollY > headtop) {

        //code correctly reaches this point as alerts show
        //alert('got here');

        //position the header row to the same as the scroll position 
        $("tr[name='headerrow']").offset({ top: scrollY, left: headleft });
    }
}
```

I can't get the row to move.  There are no error message to be seen on the various browsers developer tools.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:  I tried calling the `offset()` function on the children of the row (i.e. all of the `<th>` elements) like this:

```
$("tr[name='headerrow']").children().offset({ top: scrollY, left: headleft });
```

This now works but of course, they're all pushed over to the left because I'm using the `left` value of the header row itself... I'll keep this updated with my progress but in the meantime any assistance is appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Use the `children()` method on the table row to allow you to change the offset of each of the `<th>` elements.  The `left` value can be omitted from the `offset()` method, i.e.

```
$("tr[name='headerrow']").children().offset({ top: scrollY });
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot set the offset to any element. You should use css method and set the top and left parameters.

Comment: Incorrect, the offset can be applied to most elements - see my edit above.  Also I can't use CSS to apply top and left because I'm not using `absolute` or `fixed` positioning.